# recommended website development tools

Tags: php, html, css, web, web-development-server

I need tips and recommendations from experts regarding the development of a new website. I am a beginner to the web development field. I have grasped the basics of HTML/CSS/Javascript/PHP/MySQL however I want to start developing an advanced feature website and I am unsure of how to start. I'm guessing that professionals do not start coding **from scratch** and that there are certain libraries that could make life easier.

The elements of this website are :
-users can signup/login and edit profiles
-users can search website content
 
-users can exchange messages

What are the best languages, tools, programs, frameworks, libraries that should help me complete this project in a reasonable amount of time. I know this is a very broad topic but please recommend anything helpful so that I can start heading in the right direction.

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap, jQuery (must have for every project), AngularJS...

Comment: PHP is good for signup/login. And I also heard people use Java for exchanging messages. For searching web contents, it could be written in anything, ASP.NET like this site, or PHP, or Python, Ruby, Java... etc..

Comment: You start by defining the requirements and then draw sketches of your business logic and models (entity relationship).

Comment: Totally agree with DanFromGermany. You will never build a house without having a plan nor traveling without a goal. This will end in a desaster.
Believe me that I know that. :-(
I was trying many projects to start from scratch without having a plan. Just start and see what happens. Yeah, never will do that again in life. Every project at the end was nearly a mess. To much to fix and not stable enough.

Also you will think it is a waste of time to plan and write everything down you will be lucky at the end that you had spent this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Laravel` is the new star of the web application development community. Fairly easy to use, great documentation, many many packages/modules/extensions. I personally had problems choosing between `Laravel` and `Yii`, but this chart helped me a lot:

http://vschart.com/compare/laravel/vs/yii

You might also want to check out:

http://www.phpframeworks.com/

Beside PHP Frameworks, there are tons of great resources out there (check out GitHub). Gotta love the 2010's.

Comment: Hey, nice comparison. I totally agree Laravel is worth to focus on it. I started with it while version 4 was in beta status and I'm totally happy that I found Laravel. In earlier time I often used Zend Framework but version started to be extremly complex. So god bless that therewas Laravel 4.

@Houssam You will find on Youtube many tutorials for Laravel 4. Also for signup/login.